# Sessions in laravel 5.3 don't start

Tags: laravel-5

I am having problems with storing values in a session. I am using laravel 5.3 on xampp local host. I have tried the following but when I try to access the session is empty:

```
//using global session helper method
$variable = session(['exam'=>$exam]);
$exam = session('exam');
echo $exam; //exam is always empty

//I have also tried this
public function myControllermethod(Request $request)
{
$exam = $request->session()->put('exam',$exam);
//get the session
$exam = $request->session()->get('exam');
echo $exam // this approach returns the following exception

}
```

**RuntimeException in Request.php line 905:
Session store not set on request.**
I have tried both the file and database drivers without lack. Sessions are actually not being registered at all. `Session::get('key')` also do not work,

How can I start sessions in laravel 5.3. Any Help?

Comment: Have you set an App key in .env file? If not create a one using terminal with "php artisan key:generate" command

Comment: Yes the key is set

Comment: Ok, clear the cache of the application and then create a new key and try.

Comment: Same thing even after clearing application cache and regenerating the key.

Comment: What do you have as your session driver in `.env` ?